# Mapping multiple functions, in order, over a single list

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

I would like to map three different functions, in order, over a single list. To demonstrate what I mean, say we want to do the following three mappings:

```
(map foo mylist)
(map bar mylist)
(map foobar mylist)
```

If we define mylist as `'(1 2 3)`, and we run the above functions one at a time, we get:

```
(map foo mylist)     ===>  (foo1 foo2 foo3)
(map bar mylist)     ===>  (bar1 bar2 bar3)
(map foobar mylist)  ===>  (foobar1 foobar2 foobar3)
```

Instead, I would like the output to be in the following format:

```
===>  ((foo1 bar1 foobar1) (foo2 bar2 foobar2) (foo3 bar3 foobar3))
```

How would you go about this?

Comment: One of the reasons for closing questions on StackOverflow is that "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist."  I think you've explained very clearly what the  task is, and what the output should be (thank you!).  Have you attempted solutions at this problem yet?  If so, can you include them?  What didn't work about them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can nest two `map`s to achieve the desired effect:

```
(map (lambda (e)
       (map (lambda (f) (f e))
            myfuncs))
     mylist)
```

In the above `mylist` is the input list and `myfuncs` is the list of functions. For example, these lists:

```
(define myfuncs (list sqrt square cube))
(define mylist '(1 2 3))
```

... Will produce this output:

```
'((1 1 1) (1.4142135623730951 4 8) (1.7320508075688772 9 27))
```