# Call several functions with the same value

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have various functions and I want to call each function with the same value. For instance, 
I have these functions:

```
(defun OP1 (arg) ( + 1 arg) )
(defun OP2 (arg) ( + 2 arg) )
(defun OP3 (arg) ( + 3 arg) )
```

And a list containing the name of each function:

```
(defconstant *OPERATORS* '(OP1 OP2 OP3))
```

So far, I'm trying:

```
(defun TEST (argument) (dolist (n *OPERATORS*) (n argument) ) )
```

I've tried using `eval`, `mapcar`, and `apply`, but these haven't worked.

This is just a simplified example; the program that I'm writing has eight functions that are needed to expand nodes in a search tree, but for the moment, this example should suffice.

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate, but you may find [Mapping multiple functions, in order, over a single list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19145726/1281433) relevant.

Comment: Thanks to everybody, and specially to Joshua Taylor, for correct my bad english and give detailed answers, i'm gonna mark this as solved. Thank you very much for help this noob.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped!  I hope that others will find it useful in the future as well.  I rolled back your edit that added "[SOLVED]" to the title.  There's no need to add that;  when searching for questions, the UI makes it clear whether an answer has been accepted for a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other answers have provided some idiomatic solutions with `mapcar`.  One pointed out that you might want a list of functions (which `*operators*` isn't) instead of a list of symbols  (which `*operators*` is), but it's OK in Common Lisp to `funcall` a symbol.  It's probably more common to use some kind of mapping construction (e.g., `mapcar`) for this, but since you've provided code using `dolist`, I think it's worth looking at how you can do this iteratively, too.  Let's cover the (probably more idiomatic) solution with mapping first, though.

### Mapping

You have a fixed argument, `argument`, and you want to be able to take a function `function` and call it with that `argument.  We can abstract this as a function:

```lisp
(lambda (function)
  (funcall function argument))
```

Now, we want to call this function with each of the operations that you've defined.  This is simple to do with [`mapcar`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm):

```lisp
(defun test (argument)
  (mapcar (lambda (function)
            (funcall function argument))
          *operators*))
```

Instead of operators, you could also write `'(op1 op2 op3)` or `(list 'op1 'op2 'op3)`, which are lists of symbols, or `(list #'op1 #'op2 #'op3)` which is a list of functions.  All of these work because [`funcall`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_funcal.htm) takes a [*function designator*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_f.htm#function_designator) as its first argument, and a function designator is

> an object that denotes a function and that is one of: a symbol (denoting the function named by that symbol in the global environment), or a function (denoting itself).

### Iteratively

You can do this using `dolist`. The [documentation for  actually shows that `dolist` has a few more tricks up its sleeve. The full syntax is from [the documentation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_dolist.htm)

```lisp
dolist (var list-form [result-form]) declaration* {tag | statement}*
```

We don't need to worry about declarations here, and we won't be using any tags, but notice that optional *result-form*.  You can specify a form to produce the value that `dolist` returns;  you don't have to accept its default `nil`.  The common idiom for collecting values into a list in an iterative loop is to `push` each value into a new list, and then return the `reverse` of that list.  Since the new list doesn't share structure with anything else, we usually reverse it destructively using `nreverse`.  Your loop would become

```lisp
(defun test (argument)
  (let ((results '()))
    (dolist (op *operators* (nreverse results))
      (push (funcall op argument) results))))
```

Stylistically, I don't like that `let` that just introduces a single value, and would probably use an `&aux` variable in the function (but this is a matter of taste, not correctness):

```lisp
(defun test (argument &aux (results '()))
  (dolist (op *operators* (nreverse results))
    (push (funcall op argument) results)))
```

You could also conveniently use [`loop`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm) for this:

```lisp
(defun test2 (argument)
  (loop for op in *operators*
     collect (funcall op argument)))
```

You can also do somewhat succinctly, but perhaps less readably, using [`do`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_do_do.htm):

```lisp
(defun test3a (argument)
  (do ((results '() (list* (funcall (first operators) argument) results))
       (operators *operators* (rest operators)))
      ((endp operators) (nreverse results))))
```

This says that on the first iteration, `results` and `operators` are initialized with `'()` and `*operators*`, respectively.  The loop terminates when `operators` is the empty list, and whenever it terminates, the return value is `(nreverse results)`.  On successive iterations, `results` is a assigned new value, `(list* (funcall (first operators) argument) results)`, which is just like `push`ing the next value onto results, and `operators` is updated to `(rest operators)`.

Comment: Since I've nuked my answer (since it is probably more like Scheme and less like CL; Schemers generally can't get their heads around funcalling symbols, for example), you may want to modify your answer to address the most idiomatic way to write what the OP is intending. :-)

Comment: I'll add it. The concept of funcalling symbols isn't all that strange when looked at in the context of _designators_.  E.g., symbols, strings, and characters are all string designators, because there's a obvious string corresponding to each (the symbol name, the string itself, and the string of length one containing just the character).  Funcall takes function designators, which are either functions or symbols with a `symbol-function`.  I find that this perspective reduces some of the impression that Common Lisp just has a bunch of weird edge cases;  this be madness, yet there is method in't.

Answer (score 2):

1. FUNCALL works with symbols.
2. From the department of silly tricks.

```lisp
(defconstant *operators* '(op1 op2 o3))

(defun test (&rest arg)
  (setf (cdr arg) arg)
  (mapcar #'funcall *operators* arg))
```

Comment: This is clever.  It took a second to see what you did with the `setf` there.  (I usually see `(nconc x x)`.  However, `mapcar` requires that its arguments be proper lists, so calling it with that circular list is undefined behavior. (Most implementations will do what you'd expect, though.)  Also, since if no arguments are passed to `test`, then the `setf` fails.

Comment: That's true, but are there any implementations that bothers to check that?

Comment: I actually thought I'd used one that does, and fired up SBCL, CCL, and CLISP to check, but maybe I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

There's a library, which is almost mandatory in any anywhat complex project: Alexandria. It has many useful functions, and there's also something that would make your code prettier / less verbose and more conscious.

Say, you wanted to call a number of functions with the same value. Here's how you'd do it:

```
(ql:quickload "alexandria")

(use-package :alexandria)

(defun example-rcurry (value)
  "Calls `listp', `string' and `numberp' with VALUE and returns
a list of results"
  (let ((predicates '(listp stringp numberp)))
    (mapcar (rcurry #'funcall value) predicates)))

(example-rcurry 42) ;; (NIL NIL T)
(example-rcurry "42") ;; (NIL T NIL)

(defun example-compose (value)
  "Calls `complexp' with the result of calling `sqrt'
with the result of calling `parse-integer' on VALUE"
  (let ((predicates '(complexp sqrt parse-integer)))
    (funcall (apply #'compose predicates) value)))

(example-compose "0") ;; NIL
(example-compose "-1") ;; T
```

Functions `rcurry` and `compose` are from Alexandria package.