# DrRacket - I got a hint that local needs to be used here...but how?

Tags: local, racket

Design at-0. The function consumes a list of functions from numbers to numbers and produces the list of results of applying these functions to 0.

Comment: My hint is that you should use `map`, not necessarily `local`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mapping multiple functions, in order, over a single list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145726/mapping-multiple-functions-in-order-over-a-single-list).  That question is about a list of functions and a list of values, but its solution works here if the list of values is `'(0)`, so you should be able to distill that answer into a more specific one for this question.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Indeed, and my answer is basically just a simplified form of Óscar's answer, so I'm perplexed about why somebody felt compelled to downvote my answer. :-(

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Yes, I was surprised to see that too.  It wasn't me, but I expect that maybe it's because the OP _really_ wants to use `local` for some reason, and it doesn't.  I'm not really sure what purpose local would serve here, but I suppose one could, instead of pasing an anonymous `(lambda ...)` to `map`, could define that function with `local`, and then do `(map that-function funcs)`.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the straightforward solution I can think of uses `map`, not `local`. Now, of course, if you're using a student language that doesn't support `map`, that's a different story. Anyway, here's a skeletal solution for you:

```
(define (at-0 funcs)
  (map (lambda <???>
         (<???> <???>))
       funcs))
```